# PCI Compliance - Non authenticated DB

Tags: security, mongodb, pci-dss, pci-compliance

I have no idea where to go for PCI compliance questions, so I'd thought I'd give SO a shot.  If someone can point me in the right direction of where I can go to ask questions, please share.  I'll be happy to mark that as an answer as well.

If a PCI compliant site connects to a database that stores no user info, but does contain HTML and JavaScript snippets that could get rendered during the payment process, would this database need to have authentication to remain PCI compliant?  I am evaluating MongoDB and found that it does not provide auth when configured with replica sets.

Comment: I don't know too much about PCI compliance but do you *really* need replica sets? That said I believe they are addressing this in the next version ... http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1469

Comment: You could try posting at http://security.stackexchange.com/, but any answer you get (here or there) would still need to be validated by *your* QSA.

Comment: There's a good forum for this question at http://www.pciknowledgebase.com/ and it tends to be frequented by Qualified Security Assessors.  In fact, one of the forum topics is "Ask a QSA".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A several part answer:

- As I said in my comment up top, I am not a QSA (specifically not *your* QSA), and not authorized to permit you one way or the other. For a definitive answer you need *your* QSA to sign off on it. (Hmm, IANAQSA is the new IANAL....?)
- Strictly speaking, PCI does *not*: "Authenticate all access to any database **containing cardholder data**"
- While you might not need Authentication to the DB, you *do* need to segregate it on an internal network, seperated from the DMZ, as per PCI DSS requirement 1.3.7.
- According to requirement 6.1 you still need to ensure patches (it mentions databases, but nothing about *CHD* databases).
- All that said, from a security standpoint, you should consider that while *stealing* data from the database might be a non-issue, *injecting* code *into* your database could be a critical vulnerability, ala Persistent XSS. Which would of course indirectly invalidate your PCI compliance, as per requirement 6.5.1.

Again, you might get some better answers over on http://security.stackexchance.com/ ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to say no per the requirements of PCI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard#Requirements

You are not housing any personal information in the database and if you protect mongodb with firewalls and continually monitor, you may be in compliance.  If you are pretty worried about that I would get an auditing firm to check it out.